# Strange behavior in file reading in C

Tags: c, file, csv, io

So I want to read some data from a csv file.

But fgets keeps giving me NULL in the while loop. It works fine outside the while loop.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious here.

Edit: I just cleaned up the code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

FILE *input_file = fopen("free-zipcode-database-Primary.csv","r");
char buffer[1024];

if (input_file == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Cannot open input file.\n");
}



int count = 0; // to skip the first line in csv that contains the titles


while (1)
{


    if (count == 0) 
    {
        continue;
    }

    if (fgets(buffer, 1024, input_file) != NULL)
    {
        puts(buffer);
        parseDataFromCSV(buffer);
    } else {
        break;
    }




    count++;

} 


    fclose(input_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Here's the working code.

```
FILE *input_file = fopen("free-zipcode-database-Primary.csv","r");
char buffer[1024];

if (input_file == 0) 
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Cannot open input file.\n");
}

/* skip the first line in csv file */
fgets(buffer, 1024, input_file);
while (1)
{

    if (fgets(buffer, 1024, input_file) != NULL)
    {
        puts(buffer);
        parseDataFromCSV(buffer);
        bzero(buffer,1024);
        break;
    } else {
        break;
    }


} 


fclose(input_file);
```

Comment: `if (fgets(buffer, 1024, input_file) != NULL)` has a `!=`, but `if (fgets(buffer, 1024, input_file) == NULL)` has a `==`. Is that on purpose?

Comment: How many characters are read into `buffer` on the first call? Maybe the EOL character is not being recognized and everything appears to be on one line? Also, the way that's written, the first line will be read outside the loop, then the second line skipped with lines 3+ being processed.

Comment: @Downvoter Yes, it is to check if fgets returns NULL, and it does but I'm not sure why. I'm going to edit the code.

Comment: @ChrisRyding: I was testing it before. Sorry about the confusion. Let me edit the code to clean it up.

Comment: `if (count == 0) 
    {
        continue;
    }` : make infinite loop.

Comment: Whats the point of doing `bzero()`? This has no use whatsoever, drop that from your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have infinite loop inside while loop.

```
if (count == 0) {
    continue;
}
```